# How to use ng-flexmonster with Angular Universal?

Tags: angular-universal

[ng-flexmonster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-flexmonster) is not working with Angular Universal.

I am trying to add server-side rendering capability to my existing Angular (v7.0.3) application. But I am having some issue with ng-flexmonster(v2.7.11). I am getting *window is not defined* ReferenceError (Stack Trace included in the end) after running `node dist/server`.

After much investigation, I have zeroed down the issue to two components of a module which uses ng-flexmonster's FlexMonsterPivotModule and FlexMonster component. I have also wrapped all ts and html code where that pivot component is used with `isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` checks. However, I am still getting the same error. So, I digged deeper and found that inside FlexMonster component's ts file there is `import * as Flexmonster from 'flexmonster';` right at the top which actually imports the *FlexMonster* js package and references browser *window* object.

So, my question is "Is there a way to use this type of package with Angular Universal (SSR) so that the flexmonster is imported only in browser?".

```
D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:396797
__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));a.Flexmonster=b()})(window,function(){return function(a){'use strict';
B6jj.a71="fm-filtered";j6jj.z9F="font-family";h6jj.o81="linear";m6jj.J2v="columnSortTuple";w6jj.j7F="currencySymbol";w6jj.v8p="truestyle";j6jj.V9F="padding-left";
I6jj.u3p="data-index";I6jj.K2p="week";m6jj.q2v="lastRowsTupleInteracted";T6jj.i8V=2;I6jj.F8p="rgb(255,255,255)";B6jj.u21="password";m6jj.M2v="extendedDataWidth";
h6jj.C81=".level";F6jj.W5y="useToken";h6jj.V91="fm-text-display";j6jj.O5F="defaultHierarchySortName";j6jj.B9F="class='";h6jj.P81="dx";h6jj.G51="fm-content";
j6jj.L9F=".{0}{{1}}\n";I6jj.g3p="label";w6jj.a2F="column";T6jj.w6p=4759;j6jj.Y1v="style";T6jj.j5V=400;w6jj.q3F="credentials";F6jj.N8y="fm-ui-col";B6jj.R9v="D4+";
I6jj.n4p=",";I6jj.V3p="originalCaption";I6jj.d0p="ntr";m6jj.i2v="columnCount";h6jj.i4y="fm-moreicon- 

ReferenceError: window is not defined    
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:396797:122)    
at Object.module.exports (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:397346:30)    
at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:20:30)    
at Module.__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:396587:69)    
at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:20:30)    
at Object.ng-flexmonster (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:223596:18)    
at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:129039:30)    
at Module../node_modules/ng-flexmonster/ng-flexmonster.ngfactory.js (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:151859:72)    
at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:129039:30)    
at Module../src/app/dashboard/dashboard-report/flex-grid/flex-grid.component.ngfactory.js (D:\Projects\src\Portal-RnD\Portal-Features-1-SSR-Node-Angular-Guide\src\portal-ui\dist\server.js:172922:112)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by using webpack's NormalModuleReplacementPlugin. At first, I created a directory called *server-mocks* under *src* directory. In there, I created a sub-directory called *flexmonster* and put the following JS file in there named *mock-flexmonster.js*. The js file contains Flexmonster namespace and properties that are needed in my app.

```
(function() {
  var Flexmonster = {
    Format: {},
    Options: {},
    Report: {},
    Slice: {},
    Toolbar: {},
    CellData: {},
    CellBuilder: {}
  };

  return Flexmonster;
})();
```

After that, I added the following plugin settings in `plugins` array inside *webpack.server.config.js*.

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes ReferenceError: window is not defined coming from flexmonster
      /^flexmonster$/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'server-mocks', 'flexmonster', 'mock-flexmonster.js')
    )
```

This solution was found in Angular's universal-starter repository issues section. Here is comment [link](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/470#issuecomment-336602788).